# GCC warns about gettid() syscall wrapper, with glibc 2.30-8

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, glibc

[man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettid.2.html) and [SO post#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680550/c-gettid-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)/[SO post#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565177/call-gettid-witin-glibc) all suggest that `gettid()` was implemented in glibc 2.30. I think I am using *GLIBC 2.30-8*, according to `ldd --version`, but `gcc` still complains - *warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gettid’; did you mean ‘getgid’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]*. I can ignore the warning, and the program runs fine.

The header I tried to use with `gettid()` was `<sys/types.h>`, following the man page. Did I miss something?

Calling `syscall(SYS_gettid)` with header `<sys/syscall.h>` triggers no warning from `gcc`.

Comment: What bigger-picture problem are you trying to solve by using `gettid()`? Just curiosity? Working with threads?

Comment: I think you need `#include <unistd.h>` even though the manpage doesn't say that. `sys/types.h` was needed for `pid_t` pre v2.30, but `unistd.h` includes that anyway.

Comment: @SteveFriedl I was playing with nptl pthread, and poking around the glibc implementation.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>` change to `#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>`. Please read the `NOTE:` in [feature_test_macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html). So, are you sure that after that change it still triggers the warning? What would be the output of `grep gettid -r /usr/include/bits/`?

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk, that was indeed the issue. Craig's answer covered this in more detail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note: This is so new, it shouldn't be relied upon without some conditions. And, can probably *never* be relied upon.

See below.

---

Until February 2019, this is what the manpage said:

From: `man gettid`:

> Note: There is no glibc wrapper for this system call; see NOTES.

And, from NOTES:

> Glibc does not provide a wrapper for this system call;  call  it  using `syscall(2)`.

See the remainder of the NOTES section for more details. It's because they want you to use something else that is `pthread_self` compatible.

It's a `glibc` quirk/philosophy that I, personally, don't agree with.

Because, it is sometimes *necessary* to use the real/linux `tid` value.

---

The new way is [as of February 2019, per Joseph]:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
```

to get a `gettid` declaration.

**But ...**

This can *never* be relied upon [without a `#if/#ifdef`] because the `gettid` *syscall* has been around since linux 2.4, circa 2004.

Thus, it has taken `glibc` **15 years** to add a wrapper function!?!? :-( IMO, too little, too late.

When using the new method, it breaks backwards compatibility with all distros that have been published in that 15 year period.

So, ignoring this and continuing to use `syscall` is the way to go. It's the *simplest* way to maintain forward/backward compatibility.

We *could* create the wrapper, but it's more complex [something like]:

```
#if __GLIBC_PREREQ(2,30)
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>

#else

#include <sys/syscall.h>

pid_t
gettid(void)
{

    return syscall(SYS_gettid);
}
#endif
```

In fact, it's even more complex than that because we have to ensure we have a definition of `__GLIBC_PREREQ` [and `__GLIBC__` and `__GLIBC_MINOR__`] *before* we start including things.

And, getting that right is problematic. So, one would probably be *forced* to always do:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
```

And, *then* add the `#if` afterwards. Or, whatever the actual arcane way would be [which I can't personally test because I'm on a system that uses the old method].

It's *messy* and [IMO] not worth the trouble.

---

And, it's even worse.

Because the old method has been around for so long, many apps have already defined their own `gettid` wrapper function. So, the new declaration may collide with this.

So, without doing anything, a developer could recompile their [previously] working code and the build will now error out.

To prevent this, `unistd.h` should probably *only* declare `gettid` if the user has put some `#define` before including it (similar to `_GNU_SOURCE`) like:

```
#define _DECLARE_GETTID
#include <unistd.h>
```

---

And, because the new method breaks 15 years of compatibility, the manpage needs to document this fact and explain the old method.

Because, developers trying to write cross platform code, across multiple kernel versions, and multiple `glibc` versions, need to know about this.

---

**UPDATE:**

> There's very good reason it was not added before - it was not a supported abstraction for application use.

That still doesn't give them license to break backwards compatibility.

And, the missing functionality had to be synthesized for special apps (e.g. those that worked closely with a given device driver)

> For a long time

15+ years ...

> glibc was entertaining the idea of possible thread models where the kernel tid would not be an invariant for the thread lifetime.

The kernel knows nothing of `pthread_t`. It only knows about `tid`. That is how an application has to communicate with the kernel (e.g. `tgkill`).

There is nothing in the *kernel's* model that would change a `tid` midstream, any more than it would change a `pid` on a process in the middle of its execution.

That's because the kernel treats a `tid` just like a `pid` for purposes of scheduling. There is a task struct [indexed/identified by `pid/tid`] for each process and each thread.

To do otherwise, would require a major overhaul of all kernel schedulers, task/thread hierarchies, etc. So, `glibc` couldn't possibly do this alone. And, to what end?

After the `clone` syscall to create a thread [with the option to use the same address space], it's largely an invisible distinction, and a thread gets equal weight when being scheduled [based on scheduler and task priority].

That is one of the great benefits of the kernel's approach: that tasks/threads *are* first class citizens when being scheduled [unlike WinX].

*Side note:* I had to program a realtime embedded H/W H.264 video encoder and had to deal with the precursor to `nptl` [namely `linuxthreads`(?)] and it caused serious issues regarding throughput and latency. Fortunately, `nptl` came along before we had to ship. The difference was night and day.

> It was only after relatively recent discussions that it was deemed ok.

The *kernel* [and/or POSIX] define the semantics, not `glibc`. glibc gets to follow and implement, not dictate.

And, because the `glibc` people were being recalcitrant [and *obnoxious*], and took 15 years to decide [the *obvious*], IMO, they've lost any bargaining rights on this matter.

Comment: Your information is out of date. There's been a glibc wrapper for gettid since February 2019 (commit 1d0fc213824eaa2a8f8c4385daaa698ee8fb7c92), and the current man page no longer says that there isn't one.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Hardly worth a DV. That is so new, that relying on it will break on most current/stable distros [my ubuntu 18.02 updated a few days ago]. Better to wait a year or so, and then go direct. But, adding the wrapper with a conditional on the libc version would be okay. The `gettid` syscall has been around since linux 2.4, circa 2004, so `glibc` is finally adding a wrapper after **16 years**!?!?!? So, relying on the `unistd.h` wrapper _without_ a `#if/#ifdef` will break a _lot_ of backwards compatibility.

Comment: It was added in February of last year, not this year, and in glibc 2.30, not 2.80. Anyway, I fixed those things and removed my downvote.

Comment: There's very good reason it was not added before - it was not a supported abstraction for application use. For a long time glibc was entertaining the idea of possible thread models where the kernel tid would not be an invariant for the thread lifetime. It was only after relatively recent discussions that it was deemed ok.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I don't think they're exonerated. I've added an update as to why I think so.

Comment: Joseph's answer works, and Craig's gives much more background information. Thank you all.

Answer (score 8):

The man page's information on that function is wrong. Instead of `#include <sys/types.h>`, do this:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
```

I sent an email to the man-pages mailing list asking this to be corrected.

Comment: Hi Joesph, I tried with an very old gcc version and it works. https://wandbox.org/permlink/oQf8xPjRWZl1Zkf8 . Do they backport this wrapper?

Comment: @Rick This is in glibc, not gcc, so your gcc version has nothing to do with it.

Comment: But normally old version gcc comes with old glibc and I picked a very old gcc version. Maybe the wandbox website always uses a newer glibc. Anyway, I created a Ubuntu 14.04.1 and `ldd --version` gives `ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.13) 2.19`. The [result](https://pastebin.com/CCKC7xWd) is it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Rick gcc doesn't come with glibc at all. It just uses the system one.